# Conditionality Notation, Language, Concepts.

Tags: notation, elementary-probability

I've learned my entire 2 days of probability theory via wikipedia. So this is bothering me: how is it that

$$P(A | B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} \tag{1}$$

and two events are called *independent* when

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B) \tag{2}$$

In (1), we need $P(A\cap B)$ to be zero to say that $P(A)$ *does not* depend on $B$, but in (2) it's clear that we need $P(A\cap B)$ to be nonzero to say the same thing: $P(A)$ *does not* depend on $B$.

If I look at this through the lens of sets, the independence of $A$ and $B$ would imply $A \cap B = \emptyset$. I would expect, like in (1), that $P(\emptyset) = 0$. But it's also kind of obvious—thinking about real life— that independent events can occur at the same *time*. Is (2) alluding to simultaneity, and (1) alluding to something else, maybe something physical?

I think these are different concepts with similar notations, or maybe I'm just fried.

Comment: $A$ does not depend on $B$ means that $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$:  the presence (or not) of $B$ makes no difference.  This has nothing to do with anyone's probability being $0$.

Comment: If $P(A\cap B)=0$ we say that $A$ and $B$ happening simultaneously is an impossible event.  In most discrete scenarios (*the type you would be most familiar with*) this would occur when $A\cap B=\emptyset$, where we say that $A$ and $B$ are [*mutually exclusive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity), i.e. they cannot happen simultaneously.  Mutual exclusivity and Independence are two very different concepts that have little to do with one another.

Answer (score 1):

> > $$P(A | B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} \tag{1}$$
>
> In (1), we need $P(A\cap B)$ to be zero to say that $P(A)$ *does not* depend on $B$, ...

No, you are confusing *independence* with *disjointness*.   $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=0$ means the intersection of the events has zero probability measure (ie: it is a null set).   Thus the events are considered disjoint; and that the conditional probability of $A$ when given $B$ must be $0$ because $A$ is non-probable when given that $B$ occurs.   That, of course, would indicate that the events are *dependent*.

Also, (1) is the definition of conditional probability.   It is not a statement on what is required for independence.   It actually always holds when $B$ has a non-zero probability measure, whether the events are independent or dependent.

> > $$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B) \tag{2}$$
>
> ... but in (2) it's clear that we need $P(A\cap B)$ to be nonzero to say the same thing: $P(A)$ *does not* depend on $B$.

Indeed.   The events are independent *exactly when* statement (2) holds.

Furthermore, when you apply (2) as a substitution in (1) you get that independence of $A$ with $B$ means $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\mathsf P(A)$; the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$ is just the probability of $A$, which is to say that the probability measure of $A$ does not depend upon conditioning on $B$.   Exactly as we should anticipate from independence. $$\mathsf P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A)\require{cancel}\cancel{\mathsf P(B)}}{\cancel{\mathsf P(B)}}\tag 3$$

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with what you say in (1)

We do **not** need $P(A \cap B) = 0$ to say that $P(A)$ does not depend on $B$. In fact, if it were $0$ then it's almost certain that your events are very much dependent.

As a (fun) example:
Let $A$ be the event that eat more than $10$ chicken wings at a wing eating contest. Let $B$ be the event that you eat less than $9$ chicken wings at the event.

We have that $P(A\cap B) = 0$ obviously, which leads to $P(A \mid B) = 0$, but that does not mean that $P(A)$ does not depend on $B$. It certainly does.

Take the formula in (1) and multiply both sides of the equation by $P(B)$. Then we get that $$P(A\cap B) = P(B)P(A\mid B)$$

If we are allowed to substitute $P(A)$ for $P(A \mid B)$, that is, the probability of $A$ is the same whether or not we know that event $B$ occurred, then we can declare independence.